# Using chrome for web development - how to dock the inspector?

Tags: dom, google-chrome, inspect

I know Firebug is the standard, but I find myself using Chrome a lot (screen space, speed, etc.) Anyway, I think their inspector is pretty good, too. Certainly good enough that I don't want to fire up FF and navigate thru a site every time that I want to take a peak at the DOM.

However, probably the most annoying part is that I can't dock the Chrome inspector to the bottom of Chrome. I see that there's a dock button, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Any tips? suggestions? Is it supposed to do something else? Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely, DOM inspectors (just like Firebug) are just as valuable as IDEs. They are definitely a tool of the trade.

Comment: I disagree! Internet Explorer is the standard when you're doing web development in ASP.NET.

Comment: IE the standard for ASP.NET development? You're kidding, right? If you're doing *anything* with Javascript, then Firebug is your best friend! Maybe one is traditionally not too much into Javascript with classic ASP.NET, but ASP.NET MVC begs for client-side Javascript coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be [something they're working on](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25) as we speak. So for now, I guess you'll just have to change the window size, to place the inspector underneath it, or whatever your preference is (except docking, of course)...

Comment: Yeah, just found that, too. Unfortunately, resizing multiple windows for a quick inspection (and then resize again after I'm done) will be a pain.

Answer (score 7):

There is now a button on chrome that allows you to dock the element inspector to the main browser window, just like firebug. It is located in the bottom left of the window and looks like a little rectangle with a smaller offset rectangle in it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah .. found my answer here. Seems like it is dockable in Safari and not in Chrome, both based on webkit.

Seems like the proposed to solution is to remove the docking button! That's unfortunate. I won't use it if I have to constantly tab back and forth.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25

Comment: Looking at the bottom of the page, it seems like they've opened it again a couple of weeks ago. So hopefully someone's working on it now. As for the resizing, that was a joke :p I have a dual monitor set up, so I actually prefer having them undocked. Inspector in one window, browser in the other.

Comment: @peirix: agreed re dual monitors but my primary development machine is a nice laptop